# $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n})^2(\sum_{1}^{n}{a_i^2 }) ^2 \ge (\sum_{1}^{n}{a_i^2 }) (\sum_{1}^{n}{b_i^2 })-(\sum_{1}^{n}{a_ib_i })^2$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

Let $a_1, a_2,....,a_n, b_1, b_2,...,b_n$, let $\frac{b_1}{a_1} = max \{\frac{b_i}{a_i}, i=1,2, \cdots n \}$ , 
$\frac{b_n}{a_n} = min \{\frac{b_i}{a_i}, i=1,2, \cdots n \}$  show that:

$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n})^2(\sum_{1}^{n}{a_i^2 }) ^2 \ge (\sum_{1}^{n}{a_i^2 }) (\sum_{1}^{n}{b_i^2 })-(\sum_{1}^{n}{a_ib_i })^2$$

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^2 \geq \left(||B||\sin\theta\right)^2$$
Where $A=\left(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_2\right)$, $B=\left(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_2\right)$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Could you show me detail? Please

Comment: Sure. We know that $$\sum_1^n a_ib_i=||A||||B||\cos\theta$$ and $$\sum_1^n a_i^2=||A||^2$$. I'm sure you can figure it out from there. This doesn't really help solve the inequality though, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
&\ \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2 - \left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i \right)^2-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^2\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2 \right)^2\\
=&\ \sum_{i,j=1}^n\left[a_i^2b_j^2- a_ib_ia_jb_j-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^2 a_i^2a_j^2\right]\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left[a_i^2b_j^2 + a_j^2b_i^2- 2a_ib_ia_jb_j-\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^2 a_i^2a_j^2\right]\\
\le&\ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left[a_i^2b_j^2 + a_j^2b_i^2- 2a_ib_ia_jb_j-\left(\frac{b_i}{a_i}-\frac{b_j}{a_j}\right)^2 a_i^2a_j^2\right]\\
=&\ 0.
\end{align*}
The inequality follows immediately.

Comment: Dear  @Gordon, thank to You very much.
Can proof the Kantorovich inequality by this ? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KantorovichInequality.html

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào: potentially possible. You can try or ask as a question here.