# Proving the Kantorovich inequality by another inequality

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I wan to use the following [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904463/frac12-fracb-1a-1-fracb-na-n2-sum-1na-i2-2-ge-s)

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ be real numbers. Let $\frac{b_1}{a_1} = \max \{\frac{b_i}{a_i}, i=1,2, \ldots, n \}$ and
> $\frac{b_n}{a_n} = \min \{\frac{b_i}{a_i}, i=1,2, \ldots, n \}$. Then, this inequality holds
> $$\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}-\frac{b_n}{a_n}\right)^2 \left(\sum_1^n a_i^2\right) ^2 \ge \left(\sum_1^n a_i^2\right) \left(\sum_1^n b_i^2\right)-\left(\sum_1^n a_i b_i\right)^2$$

to prove [the Kantorovich inequality?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KantorovichInequality.html). The Kantorovich inequality reads as

> Let $\lambda_i>0$, $\sum_1^n \lambda_i =1$, $x_1=\max\{x_i, i=1, \cdots n\}$, and $x_n=\min\{x_i, i=1, \cdots n\}$. Then, the following holds
> $$\left(\sum_1^n \lambda_i x_i \right) \left(\sum_1^n \frac{\lambda_i}{x_i}  \right) \le \left(\frac{x_1+x_n}{2\sqrt{x_1x_n}}\right)^2$$

Comment: Please include all relevant information to the problem (*e.g. hypotheses and uncommon definitions*) in the actual post.  Do not simply post links to them if you can help it.  I.e. please take the time to write what the Kantorovich inequality is here in this post.  Also take the time to display the inequality you wish to take as hypothesis here instead of linking to another question for it.  Noone wants to flip back and forth between three or four pages just to read a question.

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.bdigital.unal.edu.co/33225/1/33021-122385-1-PB.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank to You, I edited my question

Comment: @Gordon thank to dear, I edited my question

Comment: Changed the right side $\frac{x_1+x_n}{2\sqrt{x_1x_n}}$ of the last inequality to $\left(\frac{x_1+x_n}{2\sqrt{x_1x_n}}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may not be easy to directly use the inequality you mentioned at the beginning to prove the Kantorovich inequality. Here is the proof based on [this paper](http://www.bdigital.unal.edu.co/33225/1/33021-122385-1-PB.pdf.), as I commented above.

We assume that $x_n>0$. Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\frac{1}{x_i} &= -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\bigg(x_i -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i \bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{x_i} -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \frac{1}{x_i} \bigg)+1\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\lambda_i}\bigg(x_i -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i \bigg)\sqrt{\lambda_i}\bigg(\frac{1}{x_i} -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \frac{1}{x_i} \bigg)+1\\
&\le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\bigg(x_i -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i \bigg)^2 }\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\bigg(\frac{1}{x_i} -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \frac{1}{x_i}  \bigg)^2 }+1.
\end{align*}
Moreover (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426426/variance-of-random-variable/426466#426466.)),
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\bigg(x_i -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i \bigg)^2 &= \min_{a\in \mathbb{R}}\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(x_i-a)^2\\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\bigg(x_i -\frac{x_1+x_n}{2} \bigg)^2\\
&\le \frac{(x_1-x_n)^2}{4}.
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\bigg(\frac{1}{x_i} -\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \frac{1}{x_i}  \bigg)^2 &\le \frac{\big(\frac{1}{x_1}-\frac{1}{x_n}\big)^2}{4}\\
&=\frac{(x_1-x_n)^2}{4x_1^2 x_n^2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\frac{1}{x_i} & \le \frac{(x_1-x_n)^2}{4x_1x_n}+1\\
&=\frac{(x_1+x_n)^2}{4x_1x_n}.
\end{align*}